# Cannot Add Project to Websphere 7 Local Server

Tags: java, eclipse, rad

To set some context: Our team is working on moving all of our coding from WSED 5.5 to RAD 7.5.  We are using a Websphere 7.0 Server, and a ClearCase file sharing system.

Recently, we set up a view for my co-worker, and imported the existing project into her workspace (using the "Existing Projects Into Workspace" option in RAD 7.5).

After doing some testing, we've determined that she is capable of editing this code for me to see on my own workspace, and that my edits to the code can be seen on her workspace.  So we are able to edit the code perfectly fine.

However, when she tries to access her local Websphere 7.0 server, she gets  404 File Not found exception.

We've found the reason for this - the project has not been added to the server.

---

The problem is, when she right-clicks on her server, and goes to Add and Remove Projects, the two projects she imported from ClearCase do not show up to be added to the server.

I have these projects successfully installed and added to my 7.0 server, so I know it is possible to do this.

How can we make RAD 7.5 recongize the projects in her workspace so she can add them to the server?

Comment: have you tried restarting the server, and restarting rational? (and made sure their processes were killed?)

Comment: @9er Yes, to both things.

Comment: There's an option called _Allow applications containing errors to be published on the server_ (_Server_ > _WebSphere Application_ in the preferences) - might it cause the issue?

Comment: @FlasHfromRu It shouldn't...we've only got warnings, not errors.  I'll check with my co-worker, though frustratingly her machine isn't working correctly right now, so our progress in this area has been put on a standstill.

Comment: @Zibbobz, one more thing. Could you please check the values on the _Project Facets_ sections of the unsuccessful project? The idea is that there should be correct WAS runtime checked on the _Runtimes_ tab. It might not be checked and RAD might not allow to check it explicitly (still there's a workaround for that) - already spend several hours for such problem once...

Comment: @FlasHfromRu I will ask my co-worker to check on that, but I don't think it will help. I've checked on my own machine the Project Facets settings in that tab, and neither of them had the Wesphere Application v7.0 or ANY other box checked for that, yet my local server functions just fine.

Comment: @Zibbobz doublechecked at myself - possibly you're right (

But here's another try - does your co-worker have "EJB" facet checked for her projects? Unchecking it will definitely exclude the project from "Add and Remove Projects" list - just checked at my local machine.

Comment: @FlasHfromRu Well I've checked my projects again, and EJB is listed for one, with a reference to the other, so I think that might be our solution.  I will have to ask her when she gets back to check on that though.